useState vs useRef in terms of performance in React multi-input forms
When a state changes for one of the inputs, the whole page is not "rerendered", just that input field, right ? Would useRef give faster performance because there are no renders besides the initial one ?
Example with useState
import { React, useState } from "react";

export function LoginForm() {
    const [form, setForm] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setForm({ ...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Do something with form data
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input name="email" value={form.email} onChange={handleChange} />
            <input
                name="password"
                type="password"
                value={form.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    );
}

Example with useRef
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export function LoginForm() {
  // Create refs for each input field
  const emailRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something with form data
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input
          name="email"
          type="email"
          ref={emailRef}
          placeholder="Enter your email"
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
        <input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          ref={passwordRef}
          placeholder="Enter your password"
        />
      </div>

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  );
}

My understanding of React diffing and re-rendering is not very good, I hope someone here can help me understand.

React reconciliation is tuned/optimized to perform quite well, around a 60 FPS target refresh rate IIRC, or around 17ms per render cycle, it's usually Userland logic that creates issues. "When a state changes for one of the inputs, the whole page is not "rerendered", just that input field, right?" - Almost. React tries to only rerender what actually changes. The component the state belongs to will rerender itself and all it's children.

"Would useRef give faster performance because there are no renders besides the initial one ?" Maybe, marginally, since you are skipping updating state, but I doubt you would even notice it unless you had like thousands or tens of thousands of form fields to update and render. This is a really trivial thing to test though.
